# rounding off the lift, support and confidence to 4 decimals but lift becomes 1 decimal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I use Apyori API to generate a association from my data set.

```
#categorize central region into a basket
basket = (df
         .groupby(['Customer Name', 'Sub-Category'])['Quantity']
         .sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0)
         .set_index('Customer Name'))

#create a function to normalize the data
#any >1 values will return 1, any <1 values will return 0
def encode_units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x>=1:
        return 1

#apply the function to basket
basket_sets = basket.applymap(encode_units)
basket_sets
#find frequent itemset, which minimum support is at least 0.35
frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.35, use_colnames=True)

#generate rules with corresponding support, lift and confidence
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)

a = rules[(rules['lift'] >= 1) & (rules['confidence'] >= 0.8)]
t = a.sort_values(['lift', 'confidence'], ascending=False)[['antecedents', 'consequents', 'lift', 'support', 'confidence']]
```

Then I got the result of:

```
    antecedents           consequents   lift    support confidence
74  (Accessories, Storage)  (Paper) 1.114737    0.353090    0.858896
166 (Storage, Furnishings)  (Paper) 1.106141    0.378310    0.852273
170 (Phones, Storage)   (Paper) 1.103379    0.372005    0.850144
146 (Binders, Storage)  (Paper) 1.094049    0.460277    0.842956
etc...
```

How should I round off lift, support and confidence to 4 decimal places and also rest the index of the antecedents then display? Thanks

========================updates====================

I used `t.index = np.arange(1,len(t)+1)` to replace the index, but the round off I still in progress of finding the solution.

========================updates2====================

Ok I've found the answer by using

`t.lift = t.lift.apply(np.round, decimals=4)
t.support = t.support.apply(np.round, decimals=4)
t.confidence = t.confidence.apply(np.round, decimals=4)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok to answer my own question, I actually found the solution by using

`t.lift = t.lift.apply(np.round, decimals=4)
t.support = t.support.apply(np.round, decimals=4)
t.confidence = t.confidence.apply(np.round, decimals=4`